# TikZ: How to correctly scale a node drawn by "circle through"?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling, transformation

Here's an MWE showing the challenge when I tried to use `circle through` with a scaling transformation (and `transform shape`):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{through}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=left:A] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=right:B] (B) at (1,0);
\draw (A) -- (B);
\node[draw,circle through=(B)] at (A) {};
\node[draw,circle through=(A)] at (B) {};

\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm, scale=.75, transform shape]
\coordinate[label=left:A] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=right:B] (B) at (1,0);
\draw (A) -- (B);
\node[draw,circle through=(B)] at (A) {};
\node[draw,circle through=(A)] at (B) {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And it will give a graph as follows:

[image]

After such a scaling, although nodes A and B are both resized, but they are not on circles anymore. It seems that some operations are made in a wrong order.

BTW, I understand I can always use "calc" library to calculate the radius and then draw circles, but I hope I don't need to address this problem in that way. Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: Woudl `\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm, scale=.75]` and manually using a smaller font size be a workaround?

Comment: @samcarter Well, yes and no. It's acceptable to do so in my MWE; but unfortunately, I have a much more complicated graph with different font sizes. That's why I add `transform shape` in my MWE code.

Comment: This is the normal behavior: you apply the scale to all nodes. If you want to scale only the letters A and B you can use `every label/.style={transform shape}`.

Comment: @Kpym Thank you so much! I should have recalled this `every label` style. I've turned your brilliant comment into an MWE in an answer below.

Comment: If this is what you want, you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kpym provides a comment which can scale graph and label fontsize at the same time, which is the desired result. Here's an MWE based on his suggestion which solves the problem:

- `scale=0.75` multiples all coordinates by 0.75 in the graph. This scaling is actually done before `circle through`, so circles are still drawn through given points. Objects, including text fontsize, aren't scaled here. So we need the following command to help scale text fontsize.
- `every label/.style={transform shape}` ensures that fontsize of label (i.e. "A" and "B") are scaled under the same scaling factor 0.75.

MWE Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{through}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=left:A] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=right:B] (B) at (1,0);
\draw (A) -- (B);
\node[draw,circle through=(B)] at (A) {};
\node[draw,circle through=(A)] at (B) {};

\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm, scale=.75, every label/.style={transform shape}]
\coordinate[label=left:A] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=right:B] (B) at (1,0);
\draw (A) -- (B);
\node[draw,circle through=(B)] at (A) {};
\node[draw,circle through=(A)] at (B) {};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `transform canvas` in this case. (**UPDATE**: Adjusted line width.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{through}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=left:A] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=right:B] (B) at (1,0);
\draw (A) -- (B);
\node[draw,circle through=(B)] at (A) {};
\node[draw,circle through=(A)] at (B) {};

\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={scale=.75},line width=1.33\pgflinewidth] %, transform shape
\coordinate[label=left:A] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=right:B] (B) at (1,0);
\draw (A) -- (B);
\node[draw,circle through=(B)] at (A) {};
\node[draw,circle through=(A)] at (B) {};
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\path (A) --++(0.6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Occasionally this screws up the bounding box, that's why I added the path at the end.

Comment: I'd say your solution is really close to what I want, but `transform canvas` would change line width. An answer from @Kpym suits better and I've posted an MWE below. But thank you all the same!

Comment: @wklchris This is easy enough to fix. I guess you should let Kpym answer your question, see [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7623/when-is-it-acceptable-to-accept-one-owns-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your revised answer. As for answer acceptance, when users only comment, I would think they don't want to write an answer. That's why I answered it by myself because I've found exactly what I want. Of course, I've also given FULL CREDITS to Kpym as the first line of my answer. After all, there's no way to accept a comment.

Comment: @wklchris You could ask her/him to turn the comment into an answer. I guess then the explanation would be a bit more accurate. At the moment, your answer reads a bit like a statement that `every label/.style` would scale circles, which it doesn't. And note also that the answers are not only for those who ask the question, but also for other people having the same problem in the future. That's why I decided to leave mine, there are many situations in which this is the way to go, e.g. if you fill something with a pattern that you want to rescale.

Comment: Kypm has allowed me to accept the answer, so I will do it this time. Next time I will ask the commenter whether he or she minds writing an answer. BTW, I've also edited the answer to make it clearer. Thank you for telling me to keep these in mind.